# How to remove Firefox's button outline when mouse press, not click, hover or forcus

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, css

My bootstrap page has a button as follows. It has an default outline when mouse press and not released. How to remove it. I'm sure that is not mouse focus or active.

Default button

[image]

When mouse press and not release

[image]

HTML

```
<input type="button" class="advancedSearch btn" value="Advanced Search" />
```

CSS

```
.advancedSearch, .advancedSearch:focus {
  outline: none;
  background-color: #e9ece5;
  font-family: Arial, Times, serif;
  color: #333333;
  height: 35px;
}
```

Comment: Try using the default button from bootstrap then check if the issue persists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will also solve the issue. Give it a try.

```
.advancedSearch, .advancedSearch:focus {
  outline: none !important;
  background-color: #e9ece5;
  font-family: Arial, Times, serif;
  color: #333333;
  height: 35px;
}
```

Check the [fiddle](http:////jsfiddle.net/claudios/kvL8wjvu/)

Answer (score 0):

`.advancedSearch::-moz-focus-inner {
  border: 0;
}`